# Redux state doesn't update for the first time

Tags: reactjs, redux, state

I have learning redux for a few days and I have a issue. My state with people list doesn't udpate when I type first letter in filter input. State change only after typing second letter and the rest. But then filter doesn't work like it should. What do I do wrong?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please be so nice and take a minute or two and transcribe the contents of your screenshot and provide it as text. Rationale can be found at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question.

Answer (score 0):

You're filtering the people's list based on the previous state, not the new value.

That is, in your reducer, you need to update `.includes(state.filterQuery)` to `.includes(action.letter)`.